# Java - Screenshots taken with robot class have different byte amounts

Tags: java, arrays, file, byte, awtrobot

When I use the robot class to get multiple screenshots of my screen, then convert the bufferedimage to a byte array, the lengths of the byte arrays vary, sometimes by a lot. Should this be happening? I feel as though the amount of bytes in each picture would be the same.

For background I am trying to speed up a simple screen sharing program. Right now I am sending each picture as a complete byte array which works fine (but is slow). I would like to keep every picture in a buffer, then send only the changes and indexes in the byte arrays of the changes from the last picture to the next, cutting down on data sent over the socket. This isn’t working out as each screenshot has a different sized byte array.

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: `then convert the bufferedimage to a byte array,` - how? Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshots are different sizes because they've got different amounts of complexity.

You haven't included a lot of detail in your question, so I'm going to assume that the screenshot routine you're using returns a PNG image.

The PNG format isn't just an array of (red, green, blue) data with one entry for every pixel of your image. Instead, the format compresses the image data. This means that (for example) an image that was just a single flat colour would be much smaller than one where every pixel was a different colour.

Comment: Thanks for clear answer. It I wanted a format with no compression, would I use something like TIFF?

Comment: In your position, I'd be looking at something like the `getRGB(int x, int y)` method of BufferedImage, which you could use to build up the arrays of pixels you want.